# DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have this Code:

```js
    const ticketModal = new ModalBuilder()
        .setTitle('test')
        .setCustomId('test')
        .addComponents({
            "type": 1,
            "components": [{
                "type": 4,
                "custom_id": 'test',
                "style": TextInputStyle.Short,
                "label": 'test',
                "min_length": 1,
                "max_length": 4000,
                "placeholder": 'test'
            }]
        })
```

However, it always comes this:

> components[1][TAG_FIELD_MISSING]: Field "type" is required to determine the model type.

Comment: It looks like tthere is no `components[1]` here. What's the full error message?

Comment: How components[1]?

Comment: Not sure if I can understand your question. Can you add the full error message to your question?